# Unable to import matplotlib._png (pylab)

Tags: matplotlib

I am unable to `import matplotlib._png`:

> `import matplotlib._png as _png ImportError:`
>   /home/james/opt/python/virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/_png.so:
>   undefined symbol: png_set_longjmp_fn

This error prevents me from running `import pylab` (sincce this ultimately imports `matplotlib._png`).

I installed `matplotlib` from source, and made sure to add the path with local installations (`/home/james/local`) to `basedir` in `setupext.py` before running `python setup.py install`.

```
REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.7.1]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.1]
               tornado: yes [using tornado version 3.0.1]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 1.5.7]
                 pycxx: yes [Couldn't import.  Using local copy.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 16.0.10]
                   png: yes [version 1.2.10]
```

## My research so far:

As can be seen above, matplotlib seems to find version `1.2.10` even though the version that I have under `/home/james/local` is `1.6.2`:

```
$ find . -iname '*libpng*'                                                                                                  
./libpng16.so.16.1.0
./libpng16.so
./libpng16.so.16
./libpng16.a
./libpng.a
./libpng.so
./libpng16.la
./pkgconfig/libpng.pc
./pkgconfig/libpng16.pc
./libpng.la
```

More specifically, I modified the following line in `setupext.py` with:

```
return basedir_map.get(sys.platform, ['/home/james/local', '/usr/local', '/usr'])
```

but matplotlib seems to have found the system version:

```
$ locate libpng
/usr/lib/libpng.so
/usr/lib/libpng.so.3
/usr/lib/libpng.so.3.10.0
/usr/lib/libpng12.a
/usr/lib/libpng12.so
/usr/lib/libpng12.so.0
/usr/lib/libpng12.so.0.10.0
```

Could this be the problem? Why am I unable to import `matplotlib._png`?

### Update:

Looking at `setupext.py`, it looks like `python setup install` queries `pkg-config` through the `SetupPackage` method `_check_for_pkg_config` to determine the version of libpng I have installed. It turns out that `pkg-config` is returning the system installation:

```
$ pkg-config --libs libpng
-lpng12
```

even though I have updated `basedir` in matplotlib's `setupext.py`, and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make them point to the the more recent version of `libpng` that I have locally installed.

Any ideas on how to have `pkg-config` return the right version?

Comment: it is odd that it (mostly) passed the tests, but is dying when you actually use it.  This makes me think this is primarily a path issue.

Comment: Thanks @tcaswell. I think I am getting closer to the root of the problem (see my update at the top)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a `pkg-config` issue; matplotlib's installation is (unfortunately, or perhaps not) relying too much on `pkg-config`'s output.

Assuming you have build libpng the normal way, there should be a pkgconfig subdirectory in your `/home/james/local/lib`, which contains `libpng.pc` (and `libpng16.pc`). When `setupext.py` runs `pkg-config`, the latter should of course try and pick up the correct `.pc` file for libpng. For that, use the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variable and point it to the pkgconfig subdirectory:

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/james/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Then, install matplotlib again, and see that it now finds the correct libpng version:

```
$ python setup.py build
basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']
============================================================================
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: 1.1.0
                python: 2.7.4 (default, Apr  8 2013, 16:36:47)  [GCC 4.4.5]
              platform: linux2

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                 numpy: 1.7.0
             freetype2: 12.0.6

OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                libpng: 1.6.1
               Tkinter: Tkinter: 81008, Tk: 8.4, Tcl: 8.4
```

(For me, with a different PKG_CONFIG_PATH of course. Yes, I may want to upgrade some dependencies.)

Note that I didn't even alter `basedirlist`; it's just at its default.
In case `pkg-config` fails to now pick up some other package, just add more directories to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` with colons in between. But I guess this should be enough.

Comment: Thanks Evert. My `/home/james/local/lib` does not contain any `.pc` files at the moment. I presume I should create them. Do I need to write anything on them?

Comment: Actually sorry, you are right there is a folder called `pkgconfig` with two files in it (one being a symlink)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution. I tried a lot of approaches and this finally worked. One should also work out that after the steps above have been done, one needs to reinstall matplotlib. At least for me this was not clear in the first place.

Comment: @chromate True, that's implied by the `python setup.py build` command. I'll update my answer to try and rephrase that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/james/local/lib
```

and then execute Matplotlib... that would point matplotlib to your local version.

Comment: That didn't fix the problem. It looks like `matplotlib` relies on `pkg-config` to determine the libraries that I have installed.