# Issues with matplotlib._png when installing on OSX 10.6.8

Tags: matplotlib, osx-snow-leopard

I tried installing matplotlib both via pip and regular python setup.py way, and both methods result in what appears to be a successful installation. All dependencies are satisfied (including libpng).

While I can successfully import matplotlib using

```
import matplotlib
```

when I try to import pylab (or matplotlib.pyplot) I get the following

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 222, in <module>
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl.py", line 2, in <module>
    from matplotlib import axis
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as mtext
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 29, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import RendererBase
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 47, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 61, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Symbol not found: _png_create_info_struct
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I tried [Unable to import matplotlib._png (pylab)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227285/unable-to-import-matplotlib-png-pylab/16239054#16239054), but this doesn't seem to fix it.

What am I missing?